# pathological spike in postgresql load average after large delete

Tags: postgresql

I ran two deletes on a PostgreSQL 9.3.12 database against a fairly large table.  Each one required a table scan and took about ~10 minutes to complete.

While they were running clients weren't impacted.  Disk I/O was high, upwards of 70%, but that's fine.

After the second delete finished Disk I/O went to near zero and Load Average shot through the roof.  Requests were not being completed in a timely manner and since new requests continued to arrive they all stacked up.

My two theories are:

1. Something with the underlying I/O layer that caused all I/O requests to block for some period of time, or
2. Postgres acquired (and held for a non-trivial period of time) a lock needed by clients.  Either a global one or one related to the table from which rows were deleted.  This table is frequently inserted into by clients; if someone were holding a lock that blocked inserts it would definitely explain this behavior.

Any ideas?  Load was in excess of 40, which never happens in our environment even during periods of heavy load.  Network I/O was high during/after the deletes but only because they were being streamed to our replication server.

[image: CPU usage]

[image: Disk and Network I/O]

[image: Load Average]

Comment: Have you taken into account auto_vacuum, auto_analyze or bgwriter?

Comment: Not particularly, but would they hold locks for an extended period of time and block reads/inserts on the table being vaccumed or analyzed?

Comment: I turned on log_lock_waits and log_autovacuum_min_duration.  If it happens again and is caused by something related to locks then hopefully these will shed some light.

Comment: No easy dependency. But they could saturate I/O (pg internal) and cause other operations to get delayed, causing pile up of simple operations. This all is quite different from version to version. So, no clear statement. You might also try to get stack traces of running pg processes during peek time to get an idea what the processes are busy with.

Comment: Well, during the affected period, I see even "explain" statements taking ~10 seconds to complete.  At least, judging by the durations reported in the postgres log files.  That's what struck me as particularly weird.

Comment: I'd also suspect some internal datastructures deteriorating. In my case after some millions of update and insets, duration of trivial update by primary keys increase from 0.02ms to 900s. But over the last years I failed getting a small enough test case for analysis. This is why I did suggest looking at stack traces. This at least may provide some hints.